# Java: Cancel REST service method execution

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I expose an Stateless EJB as a REST service. In my POST-method, I call

```
Result r = longRunningBusinessMethod();
//return data
```

How do I go about making it possible to cancel the execution of *longRunningBusinessMethod()* from the client side? 
I thought about creating a thread for the method, and keeping all executing threads in a hashtable together with an id, so that the user can POST his id to terminate the thread. But I am sure there must be a better solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the rough design of "keeping a table of IDs" is a good starting place. Instead of terminating the thread externally, I'd probably use an ExecutorService with a thread pool, and then keep a `Map<ID, Future>`, so you can cancel the future. (Also making sure that each future removes itself from the map as it completes successfully *or* exceptionally.)

You'll also have to implement the `longRunningBusinessMethod` so that it contains enough places where it checks to see if it's been interrupted - canceling a future only sets the interrupted flag on the thread, it doesn't actually stop the code from executing. If your long-running methods already throw `InterruptedException`, it's fine as-is. Otherwise, you'll need to either add in some dummy calls, like `Thread.sleep(1)`, or manually check `Thread.interrupted()` every so often, and throw the `InterruptedException` yourself.

Comment: That's how I will do it. And I didn't know I had to manually terminate my thread. Short and related question: When I use `Future#get(30, TimeUnit.Seconds)`, will the underlying method still execute after the timeout exception has been thrown?

Comment: When the timeout exception is thrown, the underlying method _may_ still be executing. That will only set the `interrupted` flag on the thread that is executing your `longRunningBusinessMethod`, so that code still needs to be written in a way that it is interruptable.

Answer (score 2):

**Interrupting working threads is always tricky and not recommended in general.** One way around is to modify running business method to ask whether it should complete its execution. For instance:

```
public void longRunningBusinessMethod(JobContext context){
   while(someCondition) {
        if(shouldInterrupt(context)){
            log.info("Interrupting longRunningBusinessMethod");
            ...
            <close all the resources and terminate the job>
        }
   }
}
```

The`shouldInterrupt(context)` will take job context with Job ID in it and will ask DB or Cache whether it should be interrupted. Then it's easy to change 'shouldInterrup' value in DB or Cache for this particular job via the REST API.